# How would gray dust work, on a microscopic level?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, absorption

I came across an article on something called *gray dust*, a hypothetical substance explored theoretically during the early 2000s. It attempted to explain cosmological supernova observations by postulating the existence of "self-replenishing dust", ejected into intergalactic space, that absorbed light without substantial reddening - unlike the normal dust we're familiar with. Further measurements [appear to have ruled out gray dust](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2004ApJ...607..665R), however, and dark energy is the more accepted explanation for the supernova observations.

What I'm trying to find out is how gray dust works, microscopically. I did a literature search that turned up [a paper from 1999](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1999ApJ...512L..19A) proposing that thin carbon needles could produce the necessary extinction curve, and that extinction depends on the ratio of needle length to diameter. However, it didn't give a more detailed explanation of why this ratio is important, pointing instead to [an older paper](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1984ApJ...285...89D) that was beyond me, for the most part.

Essentially, why should carbon needles produce opacity curves that don't vary with wavelength, instead of the typical curves from normal dust?